# how to download oracle database to a remote server

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2

I am trying to install Oracle 11g on my client's server. In order to download it to the server, I have followed this :

1. Logged in to www.oracle.com with my client's username/pass from my desktop.
2. Accepted the Licence agreement (OTN).
3. clicked on the download link
4. When my browser started the download, I copied the download link, and
5. wget -c "the_download_link"

However, I get "403 Forbidden" error. So how do I download the Oracle db, directly to the server (rather than downloading to my Desktop first and then uploading it to the server) ?

Answer (score 1):

Using WGET to download My Oracle Support Patches (Doc ID 980924.1).

```
wget --http-user=<username> --http-password=<password> --no-check-certificate --output-document=filename "paste the copied download address here in quotes"
```

Also there are a bit different instructions in https://blogs.oracle.com/supportportal/entry/use_of_wget_instead_of_downloa but I believe things a bit changed now when flash MOS page is retired.